# downscaling entire page into one div

Tags: html, css

Ive been building this webpage, and its going great. Unfortunatley, due to resolution differences some people experience the page differently. I have been careful to use exclusively percentages to calcuate spacing and size. This is because it makes the page slightly more accesible, but also in the hopes that I could trying doing something ive thought about, this being down scaling the page. As I have been building it based mostly off my resolution, one alternative I thought about was making a div with the same aspect ratio as my computer, but a smaller size. This way I can have a window into this resolution, and other devices can experience the page as it is meant to be experienced. Since I made all measurments in percentages it should theoretically downscale correctly because it's the same aspect ratio. Before I get screamed at for bad web design, understand that the type of page I am making is very precise and so it has to be modeled by a small range of resolutions.

My first question is, is it possible? Ive been playing around with it, and after putting a div around all important elements, and changng the size, nothing happened. Im an amateur so I am not sure if it can even be done.

Second question. If it can be done, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ITS WORKING! just add "position:absolute;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you CAN just put a div around the whole thing, just make sure that it has the "position:absolute;" attribute